# How to Repaint When Drawing Outside the Form Area

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi, graphics

I am writing an application that needs to draw outside of it's main window area. I already have to code to actually do the drawing:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern void ReleaseDC(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr dc);

IntPtr desktopPtr = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(desktopPtr);

g.DrawLine(Pens.White, 0, 0, Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea.Width, Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea.Height);

g.Dispose();
ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, desktopPtr);
```

However the on paint event is an unsuitable place to put the code because it's not called when something outside of the form is redrawn. So my question is, where could this code be placed so it is called whenever part of the screen is redrawn?

Comment: You really shouldn't be painting directly on the desktop window, since you don't own it. If you want to do it, you should create a window with `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE`, and draw on that window. (You can p/invoke `SetWindowLongPtr` and `SetWindowPos` to change the a winforms form window style.)

Comment: I guess you mean like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6823357/3016335

Comment: Yes that's the ticket. Doing it that way you don't need to care what the desktop is doing, and you don't need to figure out whether the invalidated rectangle is your desired area. I assume this is for some sort of desktop widget?

Comment: Yes, but would I have to put the code to draw it in a timer?

Comment: Nope. Handle the form's `OnPaint` event and let the system tell you when you need to repaint.

Comment: How do I know when the system tells me to repaint?

Comment: The system sends a WM_PAINT which WinForms  uses to call the OnPaint event

Comment: So are these the correct imports? http://pastebin.com/gaHXHGf4

Comment: I'll post an answer in a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want content painted on the screen, you should always create a window to hold that content. Painting on the desktop (a window that you don't own) is a bad idea.

The solution is to create a window, with the extended style `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` and draw on that in response to `WM_PAINT` messages.  For a WinForms application, the runtime calls `Form.OnPaint` when you get a `WM_PAINT` so you can handle that event and do the painting there. To demonstrate:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int index);
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int index, IntPtr value);
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);

private const int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000;
private const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;

private const uint SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
private const uint SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
private const uint SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;
private const uint SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020;
private const uint StyleUpdateFlags = SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.Paint += Form1_Paint;
    this.Shown += Form1_Shown;
}

private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr currentStyle = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    int current = currentStyle.ToInt32();
    current |= WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
    SetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, new IntPtr(current));
    SetWindowPos(this.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, StyleUpdateFlags);
}

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Black);
}
```

If you want your window to float on top set the form's `TopMost` property to true. If you want your window to stick to the bottom of the Z-Order (the exact opposite of `TopMost`) then add the following logic to your form:

```
private struct WINDOWPOS
{
    public IntPtr hwnd;
    public IntPtr hwndInsertAfter;
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int cx;
    public int cy;
    public uint flags;
}
private const int WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING = 0x0046;
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING)
    {
        if (m.LParam != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            WINDOWPOS posInfo = Marshal.PtrToStructure<WINDOWPOS>(m.LParam);
            posInfo.hwndInsertAfter = HWND_BOTTOM;
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(posInfo, m.LParam, true);
            m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
            return;
        }
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

This handles the `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` window message, and prevents the window from moving up in the Z-Order by telling the window manager to put it at the bottom.

Comment: This bring an `EntryPointNotFound` exception at line 44: http://i.imgur.com/JVf1CEB.png

Comment: You're compiling 32 bit... requires a slight change to the code. See the update.

Comment: Ah thanks, didn't notice that. I changed the properties to build in x64 and works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: If you need to build x86 or any CPU you can use  `GetWindowLong` and `SetWindowLong` instead of the `Ptr` versions for this use case. I set it up that way in the answer now

Comment: Yes, well I had no problems with compiling in 64-bit, it's just VS defaults to 32-bit.